# How to push scheduled notification with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, awesome-notifications

I am using [awesome_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) package for pushing notifications through my app. I have almost completed everything but I am stuck right at the edge.

So the thing I want is the code for `pickSchedule`.

#### *First I want to pick a weekday:*

[image: this is how it looks]

#### *Secondly I want to set the time:*

[image: this is how it looks]

After selecting the weekday and time I want to push the `scheduled notification` on that particular time.

Here is the tutorial video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAq9fVn3X7U&t=3420s
The code for the particular thing that I want is on time stamp `56:59` of the video.

I could retrieve only this much of the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class NotificationWeekAndTime {
  final int dayOfTheWeek;
  final TimeOfDay timeOfDay;

  NotificationWeekAndTime({
    required this.dayOfTheWeek,
    required this.timeOfDay,
  });
}

Future<NotificationWeekAndTime?> pickSchedule(
  BuildContext context,
) async {
  List<String> weekdays = [
    'Mon',
    'Tue',
    'Wed',
    'Thu',
    'Fri',
    'Sat',
    'Sun',
  ];
  TimeOfDay? timeOfDay;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  int? selectedDay;

  await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(
          'Select day of the week',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: GoogleFonts.shadowsIntoLight().fontFamily,
            letterSpacing: 1.5,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        content: Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
          spacing: 3,
          children: [
            for (int index = 0; index < weekdays.length; index++)
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  selectedDay = index + 1;
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.teal),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  weekdays[index],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: GoogleFonts.shadowsIntoLight().fontFamily,
                    letterSpacing: 1.1,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

I need rest of the code to finish my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Here is rest of the code: [NotificationWeekAndTime]

```
  if (selectedDay != null) {
    timeOfDay = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(
          now.add(
            Duration(minutes: 1),
          ),
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                primary: Colors.teal,
              ),
            ),
            child: child!,
          );
        });

    if (timeOfDay != null) {
      return NotificationWeekAndTime(
          dayOfTheWeek: selectedDay!, timeOfDay: timeOfDay);
    }
  }
  return null;
```

### Courtesy =>

I got rest of the code from their github: https://github.com/ResoCoder/flutter-awesome-notifications-tutorial/blob/master/lib/utilities.dart
If anyone like me wants to see the code, you all can take a look here.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will create schedule notifications

```
  Future<void> showScheduledNotification(int id, String channelKey,
  String title, String body, DateTime interval) async {
String localTZ = await AwesomeNotifications().getLocalTimeZoneIdentifier();

await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
    id: id,
    channelKey: channelKey,
    title: title,
    body: body,
    locked: true,
    criticalAlert: true,
    category: NotificationCategory.Alarm,

  ),
  schedule: NotificationCalendar.fromDate(date: interval),
  actionButtons: <NotificationActionButton>[
    NotificationActionButton(key: 'remove', label: 'Stop', buttonType: ActionButtonType.DisabledAction),
  
  ],
);}
```

Comment: But I am not getting the day and time picker. Can you tell me how to get that?

Comment: @MNBWorld in order to achieve this, you need to use showTimePicker and showDatePicker