# How to schedule multiple notifications with Flutter within the same day?

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter with the `flutter_local_notifications` plugin to schedule some notifications. I am able to schedule a single notification once per day or per week as for the code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/subjects.dart';
import 'package:myapp/models/task.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;


class ReceivedNotification {
  ReceivedNotification({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.body,
    required this.payload,
  });

  final int id;
  final String? title;
  final String? body;
  final String? payload;
}

class NotificationPublisher {

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  /// Streams are created so that app can respond to notification-related events
  /// since the plugin is initialised in the `main` function
  final BehaviorSubject<ReceivedNotification> didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject =
  BehaviorSubject<ReceivedNotification>();

  final BehaviorSubject<String?> selectNotificationSubject =
  BehaviorSubject<String?>();

  final MethodChannel platform =
  const MethodChannel('dexterx.dev/myapp');

  late final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails;

  bool get didNotificationLaunchApp =>
      notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false;

  String? selectedNotificationPayload;

  Future<void> init() async {
    await _configureLocalTimeZone();

    notificationAppLaunchDetails = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    if (notificationAppLaunchDetails!.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
      selectedNotificationPayload = notificationAppLaunchDetails!.notificationResponse?.payload;
    }

    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    InitializationSettings initializationSettings = const InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
          switch (notificationResponse.notificationResponseType) {
            case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotification:
              selectNotificationSubject.add(notificationResponse.payload);
              selectedNotificationPayload = notificationResponse.payload;
              break;
            case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotificationAction:
              // if (notificationResponse.actionId == navigationActionId) {
                selectNotificationSubject.add(notificationResponse.payload);
                selectedNotificationPayload = notificationResponse.payload;
              // }
              break;
          }
        },);

    _notificationsEnabled = await _isAndroidPermissionGranted();
    _notificationsEnabled = await _requestPermissions();
    // _configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject();
    // _configureSelectNotificationSubject();
  }

  Future<void> _configureLocalTimeZone() async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final String timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
  }

  Future<bool> _isAndroidPermissionGranted() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final bool? granted = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.areNotificationsEnabled();
      return granted ?? false;
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<bool> _requestPermissions() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final bool? granted = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.requestPermission();
      return granted ?? false;
    }
    return false;
  }

  void dispose() {
    didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.close();
    selectNotificationSubject.close();
  }

  // NOTIFY

  tz.TZDateTime _scheduleTimeInstance(DateTime date, TimeOfDay time) {
    return tz.TZDateTime(
      tz.local,
      date.year,
      date.month,
      date.day,
      time.hour,
      time.minute,
    );
  }

  Future<void> zonedScheduleNotification(int notificationId, Task task) async {
    print(notificationId);
    var scheduleDT = _scheduleTimeInstance(task.scheduleDate!, task.scheduleTime!);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        notificationId,
        task.title,
        task.details,
        scheduleDT,
        const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'myapp-id',
              'myapp',
                channelDescription: 'notification channel for myapp',
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,
                ticker: 'ticker')
        ),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }

  Future<void> cancelNotification(notificationId) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(notificationId);
  }

}
```

However I need something more complicated like (example):

from 08.00 to 20.00 every hour, every Tuesday and Friday.

To achieve that do I have to create 12 X 2 distinct notifications? Can be done with only one notification via API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the flutter package to schedule notification:

> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

or

> https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications

After adding the package to your app, you can do the following to trigger notifications:

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    0,
    'scheduled title',
    'scheduled body',
    tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
    const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'your channel id', 'your channel name',
            channelDescription: 'your channel description')),
    androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
```

or if you are using awesome notification:

```
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
      id: id,
      channelKey: 'scheduled',
      title: 'wait 5 seconds to show',
      body: 'now is 5 seconds later',
      wakeUpScreen: true,
      category: NotificationCategory.Alarm,
  ),
  schedule: NotificationInterval(
      interval: 5,
      timeZone: localTimeZone,
      preciseAlarm: true,
      timezone: await AwesomeNotifications().getLocalTimeZoneIdentifier()
  );
```

Please read the complete documentation of each package for limitations.

Comment: I know that, but how to achieve the flexibility I need like in the example with that API?

Comment: You can play around with the package or if you want you can check this answer out:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299531/how-to-push-scheduled-notification-with-flutter